# Antlr4: How to identify which rule alternative was matched?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I have a grammar like the following:

```
node: '{' type ',' '"expression"' ':' rightSide '}' ;
rightSide:
    call         # callAlternative
    | identifier # identifierAlternative
    ;
```

Now in my visitor, I implement the method `visitNode(Parser.NodeContext ctx)` and want to visit the correct method for the rightSide rule, whichever alternative is matched. The `#` labels are used to generate a dedicated method for each alternative and the `righSide` rule does not have a visit-method anymore. Also the `ctx` in `visitNode` only has `ctx.rightSide()`, no `ctx.callAlternative()` and/or `ctx.identifierAlternative()`.

How can this be done?

```java
@Override
public SomeObj visitNode(Parser.NodeContext ctx) {
    // how to detect which of the two alternatives was matched? ctx only has ctx.rightSide()
    // What is the something in ctx.something ?
    if(....){ // how to decide here??
        visitIdentifierAlternative(ctx.something);
    } else visitCallAlternative(ctx.something);
    return new SomeObj();
}
@Override
public SomeObj visitIdentifierAlternative(Parser.IdentifierAlternativeContext ctx) {
    // Do things only to be done for IdentifierAlternative
    return new SomeObj();
}
@Override
public SomeObj visitCallAlternative(Parser.CallAlternativeContext ctx) {
    // Do things only to be done for CallAlternative
    return new SomeObj();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't call `visitIdentifierAlternative` or `visitCallAlternative` directly. You just call `visit`, which will then select the appropriate method on its own.

Comment: I do understand what you mean from a conceptual point of view (just implementing the visitor pattern and using the double dispatch of `visit()`). But when it comes to the practical implementation I can't get that working due to the auto-generated classes/methods of Antlr. `visit(ParseTree tree)` needs a `ParseTree` object but there are only the `Context` objects available. How is this supposed to be done correctly?
Can you please provide a MVCE for the given grammar? I already googled but could not find anything useful.

Comment: @avermaet All the `Context` classes inherit from `ParseTree`. You literally just replace your `if` statement with `visit(ctx.something);` and that's it.